# Can't run MySQL on Mac

Tags: php, mysql, macos

I've tried install LAMP to my Mac using  [this tutorial](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2015/10/install-apache-php-mysql-mac-os-x-el-capitan/). I've installed MySQL from official site to my Mac (OS X El Capitan 10.11.3). I've written aliases for mysql and mysqladmin in .bash_profile. So when I try type mysql command it responses me with 
 `error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (38)`.

I've typed perror 38 and got next: Socket operation on non-socket. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think mysql server is not running. Start it by

`sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start` and try again.

Make sure it is running by (sometimes mysqld will get killed if there is any error)

`ps aux | grep mysql`